# Passing dynamic 3D matrix to function

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I have some 3D matrix data that I can access like this: `data[x][y][z]`.

The size of each dimension is only known at run-time.

I get this data by casting a malloc with `(byte (*)[Y][Z]) malloc(…)`.

When I call this function I know the dimensions of the matrix, but not at compile-time. Thus I don't how I can declare I'm receiving a matrix like this in a function…

What would be the argument type for this data in a function declaration?

```
function(byte (*matrix)[][]) // doesn't work
```

Comment: Why don't you just do something like `function(byte *ptr, int x, int y, int z)` and manually calculate the offset from `ptr` based on `x`, `y` and `z` in `function`?

Comment: You need to tell the function how big the matrix is (and the sizes must be defined before the matrix is in the parameter list).  Assuming the sizes are in X, Y, Z, then: `function(int X, int Y, int Z, byte matrix[X][Y][Z])` or `function(int X, int Y, int Z, byte (*matrix)[Y][Z]))`.  I'd use the former; it's explicit, even if the compiler doesn't make use of the `X` in the dimension.  All the non-leading dimensions of an array need a size.  The dimensions may be a variable or a constant (C90 only allowed constants).

Comment: Nice @JonathanLeffler, I didn't know the parameters are evaluated one by one but, once evaluated, available before the evaluation of the next one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do you know how this is called? Where can I find this in some reference or C spec?

Comment: @babon I kinda could, but I'm already working with this abstraction, so lot of work to change everything now. Besides, I imagined it was possible, but wondered how… Always good to learn and stretch a bit more our familiarity with the language :-)

Comment: They are 'variable length arrays' (VLA), and are defined in the C standard.  In C99, they were mandatory; in C11, they're technically optional.  A C11 compiler could state that it does not support them by defining `__STDC_NO_VLA__`.  The relevant sections of the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) are: §6.7.6.2 Array declarators, §6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes), and marginally §6.9.1 Function definitions (most of the fireworks are in §6.7.6.3 rather than here).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It is not clear that the compiler does not make use of the `X` dimension in `function(int X, int Y, int Z, byte matrix[X][Y][Z])`. Obviously, the compiler has to evaluate `Y` and `Z` so it can address elements in the matrix. This is a normal evaluation; you can insert a `printf` there. However, the standard is unclear about whether `X` is evaluated. A while ago, I found one compiler that did not evaluate it (GCC on macOS?) and one compiler that did (MSVC?).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: By insert a `printf`, I mean this is conforming C: `#include <stdio.h>` / `void foo(int a[][printf("Hello, world.\n")]){} int main(void){foo(0);return 0;}`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: If anyone provided the `printf()` example to me for code review, they would be sent away immediately to revise the code.  However, Clang on macOS High Sierra does indeed both compile the code and print 'Hello World' when it is run.  (My default compilation give warnings for 'no previous prototype' and 'unused parameter', but nothing else.)  I suppose that if you arrange to pass an array with a second dimension of 14, it is even 'OK'.  Outside of IOCCC code, I'm not sure it is useful, though.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the function with:

```
function(size_t Y, size_t Z, byte matrix[][Y][Z])…
```

and call it with:

```
function(Y, Z, matrix);
```

C supports variable length arrays (as optional or required depending on version, but support is common in modern compilers), but the called function does not automatically know the dimensions. You have to pass them to the function in some way, and in its declaration, the function has to state the dimensions.

Note that the dimensions can be expressions generally; they do not have to be the exact parameters passed. For example, you could do this:

```
function(size_t Y, byte matrix[][2*Y][3*Y])…
```

to declare a function that takes a `matrix[something][20][30]` when `Y` is 10, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to illustrate the passing of a 3D array.  The 3D array is an array of square matrices which are to be multiplied together to produce the final result.  The code is probably not the most efficient possible, but it does illustrate that passing 3D VLA values is not very hard.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void mat_copy(int x, int y, const int src[x][y], int dst[x][y]);
static void mat_list_multiply(int x, int y, const int matlist[*][*][*], int result[*][*]);
static void mat_multiply(int x, int y, int z, const int mat1[*][*], const int mat2[*][*], int result[*][*]);
static void mat_print(const char *tag, int m, int n, const int matrix[*][*]);

int main(void)
{
    int matrices[][4][4] =
    {
        //random -n 48 -- -99 99 | commalist -n 4 -B 12 -b '{ ' -T ' },' -R -W 4
        {
            {   63,  -61,   36,  -27, },
            {   37,  -86,   44,  -14, },
            {   57,   10,   74,   23, },
            {  -74,  -52,  -87,   53, },
        },
        {
            {  -34,   89,  -71,   34, },
            {  -68,  -44,  -89,  -95, },
            {   -4,  -44,    2,   80, },
            {   66,  -33,  -19,  -65, },
        },
        {
            {  -64,   11,   54,   20, },
            {   -7,   75,   -7,  -98, },
            {   52,   48,  -96,   76, },
            {  -38,  -46,  -85,    4, },
        },
    };
    enum { NUM_MATRICES = sizeof(matrices) / sizeof(matrices[0]) };
    int result[4][4];
    mat_list_multiply(3, 4, matrices, result);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MATRICES; i++)
    {
        char name[16];
        snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "%s[%d]", "matrices", i);
        mat_print(name, 4, 4, matrices[i]);
    }
    mat_print("result", 4, 4, result);
    return 0;
}

static void mat_copy(int x, int y, const int src[x][y], int dst[x][y])
{
    memmove(dst, src, x * y * sizeof(src[0][0]));   // sizeof(src) is not OK
}

static void mat_list_multiply(int x, int y, const int matlist[x][y][y], int result[y][y])
{
    int product[y][y];
    mat_copy(y, y, matlist[0], product);
    for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
    {
        mat_multiply(y, y, y, product, matlist[i], result);
        if (i != x-1)
            mat_copy(y, y, result, product);
    }
}

static void mat_multiply(int x, int y, int z, const int mat1[x][y], const int mat2[y][z], int result[x][z])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < z; j++)
        {
            result[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < y; k++)
                 result[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
        }
    }
}

static void mat_print(const char *tag, int m, int n, const int matrix[m][n])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, m, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        const char *pad = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%s%8d", pad, matrix[i][j]);
            pad = " ";
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
matrices[0] (4x4):
      63      -61       36      -27
      37      -86       44      -14
      57       10       74       23
     -74      -52      -87       53
matrices[1] (4x4):
     -34       89      -71       34
     -68      -44      -89      -95
      -4      -44        2       80
      66      -33      -19      -65
matrices[2] (4x4):
     -64       11       54       20
      -7       75       -7      -98
      52       48      -96       76
     -38      -46      -85        4
result (4x4):
 -455910    66386 -1265422  -575600
 -509373    79435 -1545267   -14906
 -392428  -468852   -38119  -464008
  137791   727227   393114  1044774
```